# Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:os-flavor-manage:create to be performed. (HTTP 403)

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-heat

I am trying to create a flavor in `openstack` configuration, and for that i have the following command : `openstack flavor create --ram 2048 --disk 20 --vcpus 1 csirtmu.tiny1x2`.
But when i run it, i get the following error:

```
Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:os-flavor-manage:create to be performed. (HTTP 403)
```

I already tried to run it from the `pipenv shell`, but i still get the same error. I would be very thankful for every suggestion regarding a possible solution to this problem :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `openstack` account you use has simply not the permission for this operations. Per default `openstack flavor create` is only allowed for admin role.

Check the nova permission from : https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/configuration/policy.html. It could result in big problems, if every normal user could create his own flavors.